# Unable to identify symbol in stop/start/retain relay

Tags: symbol

I've been doing some research on stop/start/retain relay circuits. Here is one circuit I found online:

[image]

I'm having a hard time identifying the component(s) between L1, L2 and L3 and the motor. My thought was that it is some kind of thermal switch, but it doesn't match any of the symbols I have found online. Or it is a relay contactor, but again it doesn't match any of the symbols I have found.

Could someone please help me to identify this component(s)?

Comment: look at http://www.esterline.com/powersystems/DesignReference/RelayHandbook.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are switch contacts of relay R1.  The circle thing at top right is the coil of R1.

Comment: That was my suspicion, but that is not the way I would have represented them.

Comment: @Darth: Me neither, but it seems clear enough from context.

Comment: In electrical work, two parallel lines are commonly used to represent a normally-open contact.  Add a diagonal line across them for a normally-closed contact.